# Where does Marudot store information between browser sessions?

Tags: website, cookies

I often use a handy [Marudot iCal Event Maker](https://apps.marudot.com/ical/). This web application remembers past events that I have put into it, even though I don't log in, I clear all cookies between sessions, and I use my laptop in different places with different IP addresses. I checked my browser settings, and I don't see any local storage or flash storage. Where does this site store its information? Is it somehow creating an ID for my browser that the server can use to identify my return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by grep-ing my Firefox profile folder. Since I knew what information was stored, namely the event description, I searched for that information like this:

```
grep -Rl 'my event description' ~/.mozilla
```

That revealed that the information was stored in a file named webappsstore.sqlite, which a quick internet search revealed is where [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) is kept. So much for my session-only cookie settings.

I'm still perplexed at why Firefox's Page Info/Permissions/Maintain Offline Storage setting of "Always Ask" doesn't seem to be working...

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer
>
> This application does not collect the personal event data entered by the application user. However, it might collect statistic information on how this application is being used.
>
> In an event of an application failure, there is a chance that the event data entered by the user might be saved in the form of an application log, or a program dump.

**source: https://apps.marudot.com/ical/pageAbout.htm**